# host said: 550 IP is not allowed to send mail from gmx.de (in reply to RCPT TO command)

Tags: smtp, sendmail

This message was received by a mailing list maintainer, that one of our customers subscribed to:

```
host mailx.paritaet-bremen.de said: 550 213.30.233.146 is not allowed to send mail 
from gmx.de (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

I don't get what this is about. Some answers here suggest blacklisting, but neither host is on any black list I've searched. Seems like a misconfiguration. If so, who is to blame and how to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 7):

gmx.de has SPF record with -all:

```
v=spf1 ip4:213.165.64.0/23 ip4:74.208.5.64/26 ip4:212.227.126.128/25 ip4:212.227.15.0/25 ip4:212.227.17.0/27 ip4:74.208.4.192/26 ip4:82.165.159.0/24 -all
```

most likely your recipient's mail server checks this record any denies incoming from your IP according to the record recommendation.

Comment: After some searching, it seems SPF is a bit controversial. Do you have an oppinion whether we should use it on our customers mail server?

Comment: Instead of `-all` use `?all`. That way you can consult with SPF but not use it alone to drop incoming mail.

Comment: I don't use it. As for me it brings more mess than fixes problems. But for large services like gmx.de it could be reasonable. Many spamers use their domain addresses in From: of spam messages, so SPF might be of use. And with `-all` only, if you specify `?all` - you loose all the benefit. Yes, it will be more safe, but useless.

Answer (score -1):

The above error means that the mail from gmx.de was rejected due to spf setting. The sender domain: gmx.de have SPF setting that do not allow to send the email from the IP 213.30.233.146. The spf is to prevent any mail forgery, spam issue, email spoofing and etc. The basic SPF setting is v=spf1 a mx -all. To confirm if this string exists, log in to your cpanel>Advance DNS Zone then check for a string which looks like:

gmx.de. 14400   IN  TXT v=spf1 a mx -all    Edit   Delete

[v=spf1]: This identifies the TXT record as an SPF string.
[a]: refer to the domain IP . The domain is allowed to send mail through this A record
[mx]: refer to the domain MX record. The domain is allowed to send mail through this MX record
[-all]: No other servers are allowed to send mail from this domain

So you can click on delete to remove the string from your account first before you be able to send and receive mails normally. Once its deleted the issue will be solved.
I hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to me to add nothing to the other answer, except cpanel-related suggestions - which the OP has not indicated (s)he uses, and [which would be off-topic for SF anyway](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels).

Comment: Upvoted - Come on, this is a brand new user.  I think commenting with suggestions is merited, but are the two downvotes necessary?  Hope you give SF another shot, priscah malo!  @MadHatter has some good suggestions - please follow them.  Looking forward to seeing you around! :)

Comment: P.S. I also upvoted the "more correct"/original answer :)